# Need to bypass Login Flow for while clicking the link in Forgot Password

Tags: community, visual-workflow, loginflow, login-history

I have created a flow which asks for Verification Code, which runs properly.

However, when user goes to forgot password and enteres his email, he gets a link in email, after clicking on which he gets a Verification Code link.

THis seems inaccurate.

I tried using LoginHistory object with LoginType in the flow to bypass the entire  flow.

However in debug, for both the scenarios i.e. normal login and forgot password link login, the LoginType is same.

Is there any way I can achieve this? any check to differentiate the two logins?